# JS Image Transition Not Working

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I am unable to get the CSS opacity transition to work by adding it using JavaScript. Please let me know what is wrong with the code. http://jsfiddle.net/copperspeed/bvWbB

```
(function () {
        var myImgs = document.getElementById('vz0');
        var i = 0;

        function cycle() {

            if (i <= 3) {
                var myArray = [
                    'http://jsrun.it/assets/t/r/U/O/trUOT.jpg',
                    'http://jsrun.it/assets/6/c/Y/s/6cYsH.jpg',
                    'http://jsrun.it/assets/w/M/r/i/wMriQ.jpg',
                    'http://jsrun.it/assets/5/Q/8/f/5Q8fW.jpg'
                ];

                console.log(myArray[0]);
                myImgs.setAttribute("src", myArray[i]);

                if (myImgs.style.opacity === '0') {
                    console.log('trans');
                    myImgs.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
                    myImgs.style.transitionDuration = "1500ms";

                }
                if (myImgs.style.opacity === '1') {
                    console.log('opacity-0');
                    myImgs.style.opacity = '0';

                }


                i++;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    cycle();
                }, 3000);
```

Comment: Claude- you may have better luck using a service like jsfiddle that doesn't require login

Comment: Yes, please, use jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks but jsfiddle doesn't allow me to upload images to use.

Comment: You have already uploaded the images to jsrun.it, use them.

Comment: @imjared Here is the jsfiddle  jsfiddle.net/copperspeed/bvWbB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your script.

1. the opacity style doesn't exist on the element on initialization.  You need to account for that in your logic
2. On the second pass through, the opacity style does exist and may be 0, so that condition also needs to be accounted for
3. Your second if statement immediately reverses what you did in the first conditional.  That statement should be in an else-if
4. You are cycling only one image element in/out so your transition from one image to another won't work as expected.  You either need to change to two elements or change your transitioning strategy to accommodate the single element.

[Demo fiddle - items 1-3 above](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/bvWbB/3/)

Code changed for 1-3 above:

```
(function () {
    var myImgs = document.getElementById('vz0');

    var i = 0;

    function cycle() {
        if (i <= 3) {
            var myArray = ['http://jsrun.it/assets/t/r/U/O/trUOT.jpg', 'http://jsrun.it/assets/6/c/Y/s/6cYsH.jpg', 'http://jsrun.it/assets/w/M/r/i/wMriQ.jpg', 'http://jsrun.it/assets/5/Q/8/f/5Q8fW.jpg'];

            myImgs.setAttribute("src", myArray[i]);

            if (myImgs.style.opacity === '' || myImgs.style.opacity == 0) {
                console.log(myImgs.style.opacity + '0');
                myImgs.style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
                myImgs.style.transitionDuration = "1500ms";
                myImgs.style.opacity = 1;
            } else if (myImgs.style.opacity == 1) {
                console.log(myImgs.style.opacity + '2');
                myImgs.style.opacity = 0;
            }

            i++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                cycle();
            }, 3000);
            if (i === 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    cycle();
}());
```

For item #4 above - here is a refactored version that uses two img elements to help manage the transition in and out:

[Demo fiddle for 1-4 above](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/bvWbB/5/)

HTML:

```
<div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://jsrun.it/assets/t/r/U/O/trUOT.jpg" id="vz0" class="vzImage" alt="first" height="300" width="300" />
    <img src="http://jsrun.it/assets/t/r/U/O/trUOT.jpg" id="vz1" class="vzImage" alt="first" height="300" width="300" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}
.vzImage {
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Script:

```
(function () {
    var myImgs  = document.getElementsByClassName('vzImage');
    var myArray = ['http://jsrun.it/assets/t/r/U/O/trUOT.jpg', 
                   'http://jsrun.it/assets/6/c/Y/s/6cYsH.jpg', 
                   'http://jsrun.it/assets/w/M/r/i/wMriQ.jpg', 
                   'http://jsrun.it/assets/5/Q/8/f/5Q8fW.jpg'];

    // Consider moving this to .vsImage in stylesheet
    for(var j = 0; j < myImgs.length; ++j) {
        myImgs[j].style.transitionProperty = 'opacity';
        myImgs[j].style.transitionDuration = "1500ms";
    }

    function cycle(i) {
        var myArrayIdx = i % myArray.length;
        var imgIdx     = i % myImgs.length;
        var prevImgIdx = (i-1) % myImgs.length;

        myImgs[imgIdx].setAttribute("src", myArray[myArrayIdx]);
        myImgs[imgIdx].style.opacity = 1;

        if(myImgs[prevImgIdx]) {
            myImgs[prevImgIdx].style.opacity = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            cycle(i+1);
        }, 3000);
    }
    cycle(0);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

First rule of debugging. If something inside IF statement doesn't happen, look at the condition.
You check if `myImgs.style.opacity` equals 0 or 1. Use `console.log(myImgs.style.opacity);` and it'll show you that `myImgs.style.opacity` equals empty string. So none of your conditions ever fire.

Comment: Brain - I got it to fire but this is acting weird. It doesn't make sense why it is firing like this. Can you please explain why. http://jsfiddle.net/copperspeed/bvWbB/